# Audio feedback to electromagnets

Tags: circuit-design, ac, dc

I'm an installation artist working on an installation using two opposing 24VDC electromagnets that are out of phase to create an oscillating magnetic field that actuates a steel piano string.

What I want to do is to create a feedback loop by measuring the frequency of the string with a piezo microphone and then feeding this frequency back into the magnets. This should result in the string finding its own resonant frequency.

I can't use an audio amplifier since electromagnets create pulling force with both positive and negative voltage. Even if you connect the magnets out of phase to the amplifier, the magnetic field will still be in phase.

This means that I have to split the the positive and negative voltage picked up by the piezo microphone. After this, both voltages should gate MOSFETs that switch the magnets. One magnet should be pulling on the positive-half cycle of the audio and one should be pulling on the negative-half cycle.

What circuit would be suitable for this?

I want to use piezo microphones since eventually I want to have multiple strings vibrating, so each string needs an isolated feedback loop.

See diagram below:

[image]

Comment: The thing you pick up will be a complicated noisy click initially and far from a singular sine wave. So it should be amplified in a linear way. Best get a standard piezo preamp and then either a Class AB power amp or Class D, mainly depending on the magnet power

Comment: What's the point of two opposing electromagnets? Is the steel piano string magnetized? Does DC current run through it? For a passive wire, one electromagnet should suffice.

Comment: A piezo mic has some very strong resonances. Use a mic that is more linear like an electret mic.

Comment: The piano wire is not magnetized.  I think the idea is that the two magnets are opposed with the string in the middle.  One magnet pulls the string this way on positive half-cycles of the audio, and the other magnet pulls the string that way on the negative half-cycles.  Or something like that.

Comment: @AnalogKid Yes exactly!

Comment: Do you have access to both ends of the string - so could you pass a current through the string? This would allow the string to interact with static magnets making a magnetic field around it, and also allow you a 'natural' drive to the string, as both current directions would 'do the right thing'.

Comment: There will be an unknown phase shift between the string movement and the microphone amplifier output. So to fulfill the self resonant condition your circuit may need an adjustable phase shift element. Is there an option for capacitive or optical sensing?

Comment: @Jens capacitive sensing as in how a guitar pickup works? It would make a lot more sense than using an piezo mic indeed, thanks!

Comment: A magnetic pickup is the best solution for such a string, but if you drive the string with a magnetic field you need another sensor. The string could be partially in an optical path between an LED and a photo diode to read the position. Capacitive sensing is non trivial, because the metal area is small and the signal change is fast. A first approach could be to carefully remove the front metal of an electret mic and put it close to the (electrically grounded) string. There are other options, but this is worth an extra question.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to have "opposing" magnets; once you deflect and release the string, the string will oscillate, just as it does when it is being plucked.  The issue is that the magnetic field is proportional to the current in your electromagnet, and that current will not change instantaneously when you apply voltage to the coil.  If you hit the resonant point, the amplitude should increase, and you should be able to control the amplitude with the duty cycle of the power you are applying to the coil.  The resonance will occur at the string's tone frequency, rather than twice the frequency if you tried the push-pull approach you described.

You'll need to modify your drive circuit slightly.  I would recommend using an N-channel MOSFET for switching and adding a diode to prevent large voltage spikes from appearing on your MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRUyPg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The idea behind the opposing magnets is that they create more force on the string which I thought would result in a higher amplitude, which is important for me since the installation will be acoustic. Is this not the case?

If not the approach with one magnet would definitely be easier. 

Also, what is the purpose of the capacitor in the circuit above?

Comment: An undamped vibrating string is almost lossless.  If you think about the fact that you are adding energy to the oscillation at each pulse, you should be able to get as much amplitude as you need.

Comment: The voltage across an inductor is L * di/dt, which means that the voltage is equal to the rate of change in amperes/second of current times the inductance.  When you apply power to the inductor, its current will increase until you turn it off.  But when you switch it off, the current goes from a positive value to zero almost instantaneously, so that the rate of change (amperes per second)  can be very high, which means the voltage on the electromagnet will increased dramatically, just like a spark plug coil.  The capacitor provides a current path to help absorb the energy from this spike.

Comment: I've just adjusted the setup to 1 magnet, the amplitude seems to be stay the same indeed.

Comment: Right now I'm running the magnets on a static frequency and the tuning the string accordingly. I'll try the feedback system tomorrow. What would be a way to adjust the duty cycle of the power to the coil? Another N-channel MOSFET in-between the coil and the power supply switched by e.g. an Arduino?

Comment: I'm not an Arduino guy, but I think it must have a PWM feature that will allow you to set a frequency and duty cycle.